# What should be the top level of a Backbone.js application? A view, generic object,?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm confused about what code I should instantiate directly in Backbone.js.  Should I create a generic object `App` that instantiates my views?  Should I instantiate an `App View` that instantiates all the other views on the page and coordinates everything?  Should I create views, models and collections and attach them to the `window` ?

Also, are controllers even necessary?  So far I'm not finding any use for them and they are missing from many of the examples out there.  Should I instantiate a controller and have it create the other objects as I do in other languages' MVC frameworks?

My guess is I am free to do what I want but I would prefer some advice from somebody who has used it quite a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controllers are useful for managing the hashbang URL.

If you don't have multiple pages, states you want to save or want to use the back and forwards buttons then controllers have no use.

Most examples of backbone I've seen have a AppView class that manages views and collections.

See the [Annotated Example](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a router or controller would be the centerpiece of your application, although it may be your own hand-rolled init or global object. Backbone provides utilities to you; it doesn't provide an entire soup to nuts setup.